# Unable to create directory in /usr/share

Tags: c, linux, permissions

I have heard its a conventional practice to store program dependent files in `/usr/share/application-folder` in linux. So I'm trying to do it in my c program in a function called `load_interface_files()` for example. I am not sure if this is a good practice or not, I've heard about creating configuration files for this kind of issues.

Anyways, here's the the code I wrote to make a directory in `/usr/share`.

```
if (mkdir("/usr/share/test", S_IRUSR) == -1)
     printf("no");
```

After running the code I don't see the error message nor the created directory. But when I try the same thing for my project directory path for example, it works fine. I am not sure but I think it has to do with root privilege in order to write to `/usr/share` but I don't know how to work around this.

Some debugging info:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/share
drwxr-xr-x 314 root root 12288 Dec  1 07:39 /usr/share
```

```
$ ls -l /usr/share
total 1448
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 accerciser
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 accountsservice
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 36864 Nov 24 21:56 aclocal
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:15 aclocal-1.16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 alacarte
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 alsa
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 alsa-card-profile
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 appdata
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 app-info
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 12288 Nov 24 21:56 applications
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 application-utility
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 apr-1
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 augeas
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 autoconf
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:15 automake-1.16
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 avahi
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 awk
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 backgrounds
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 bash-completion
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:15 bison
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 brltty
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 ca-certificates
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 caffeine
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 caja
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 clang
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 clutter-1.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 cmake
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 cmus
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 cogl
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 color
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 colord
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 color-schemes
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 common-lisp
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 cracklib
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 cryptui
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 cups
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 daxctl
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 dbus-1
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 dconf
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 defaults
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 desktop-directories
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 devhelp
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 dhclient
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 dhcpcd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 dict
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 djvu
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 dnsmasq
drwxr-xr-x 237 root root 12288 Nov 24 21:56 doc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 drirc.d
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 dynamic-wallpaper-editor
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 ecryptfs-utils
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 edk2-ovmf
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 emacs
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 enchant
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 eog
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 epiphany
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 et
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 evince
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 evolution
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 evolution-data-server
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 factory
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 ffmpeg
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 file
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 file-roller
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 fish
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 five-or-more
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 flatpak
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 fonts
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 foomatic
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 four-in-a-row
drwxr-xr-x  35 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 freeoffice
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 fzf
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gcc-10.2.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 GConf
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 gdb
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gdm
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 geary
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gedit
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gegl-0.4
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 gettext
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 gettext-0.21
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Nov 23 06:01 gir-1.0
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Nov 11 15:57 git
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 git-core
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 git-gui
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 gitk
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 11 15:57 gitweb
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gjs-1.0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 glade
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 glib-2.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 gls
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 glvnd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-background-properties
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-bluetooth
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-books
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-boxes
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-builder
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-chess
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gnome-color-manager
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:16 gnome-control-center
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-documents
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-logs
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-mahjongg
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-maps
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-mines
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-nettool
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-nibbles
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-recipes
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-robots
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-session
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gnome-settings-daemon
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 gnome-shell
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-software
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-system-monitor
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-taquin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-todo
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gnome-tweaks
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-user-share
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gnome-video-effects
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 gnome-vpn-properties
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 gnupg
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 graphite2
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 graphviz
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 grilo-plugins
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 groff
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 grub
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gst-plugins-base
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 gstreamer-1.0
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gthumb
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gtk-2.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gtk-3.0
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 gtk-doc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gtk-engines
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gtksourceview-2.0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 gtksourceview-3.0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gtksourceview-4
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 gufw
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:15 guile
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gupnp-av
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 gupnp-dlna-2.0
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 gutenprint
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 gvfs
drwxr-xr-x  69 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 help
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 highlight
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 hplip
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 httpd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 hwdata
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 hwinfo
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 hwloc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 i18n
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 iagno
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 iana-etc
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 ibus
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 icons
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 icu
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 ImageMagick-7
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 imlib2
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Nov 23 06:01 info
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 installed-tests
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 iptables
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 iso-codes
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 jack-audio-connection-kit
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 java
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 kbd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 keyutils
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 kf5
drwxr-xr-x  46 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 Kvantum
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 kvantummanager
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 kvantumpreview
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 ladspa
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 lensfun
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 libalpm
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 libcaca
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 libdrm
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 libftdi
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 libgnomekbd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 libgpg-error
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 libgphoto2
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 libgphoto2_port
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 libgweather
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 libinput
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 liblouis
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 libquvi-scripts
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 libthai
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 libtool
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 libvirt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 16384 Nov 23 06:01 libwacom
drwxr-xr-x 453 root root 20480 Nov 24 21:56 licenses
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 lightsoff
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:02 lintian
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 lirc
drwxr-xr-x 302 root root 12288 Nov 10 20:00 locale
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 lollypop
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 lshw
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 lua
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 luajit-2.0.5
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 makepkg
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 31 02:06 makepkg-template
drwxr-xr-x  37 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:31 man
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 manjaro-hello
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 mate-background-properties
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 mate-panel
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 mc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:16 menu
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 mesa-demos
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Nov 23 06:31 metainfo
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Nov 24 21:56 mime
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 24 21:56 mime-info
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 26 16:06 misc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 mkinitcpio
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 mobile-broadband-provider-info
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 model
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 ModemManager
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 mousetweaks
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Nov 24 21:56 mysql-workbench
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 nano
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 nautilus
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 nautilus-python
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 netpbm
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 ntp
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 openal
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 openmpi
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 openvpn
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 orca
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 org.gnome.Characters
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 org.gnome.Music
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 org.gnome.SoundRecorder
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 org.gnome.Weather
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 osinfo
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 os-prober
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 ostree
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 Oct 22 01:46 ovmf -> /usr/share/edk2-ovmf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 Oct 22 01:46 OVMF -> /usr/share/edk2-ovmf
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 p11-kit
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 pacman
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 pacman-mirrors
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 pastebin.d
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 perl5
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 perl-image-exiftool
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 pixmaps
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 24 21:56 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 pmix
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 polari
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 ppd
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 24 21:56 proj
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 pulseaudio-ctl
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 pygobject
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 qemu
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 qlogging-categories5
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 qt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 quadrapassel
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 readline
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 rygel
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 sane
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 scan-build
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 scan-view
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 seahorse
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 shared-color-targets
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 sip
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 slsh
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 snmp
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 sounds
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 ss
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 stoken
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 sushi
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 swell-foop
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 systemd
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 t1lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 tabset
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 tali
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 tc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 telepathy
drwxr-xr-x  44 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:57 terminfo
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 texinfo
drwxr-xr-x  48 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 themes
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 thumbnailers
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 timeshift
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 tlp
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 totem
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 tracker
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 tracker3
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 tracker3-miners
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 tracker-miners
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 ufw
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 20480 Oct 19 16:00 usb_modeswitch
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 vala
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 vala-0.50
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 valadoc-0.50
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 vde2
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 vim
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:02 vulkan
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 wayland
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 wayland-protocols
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 wayland-sessions
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:01 webapp-manager
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 webapps
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:31 wine
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Oct 19 16:00 X11
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 xcb
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 xdg-desktop-portal
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Nov 10 19:35 xml
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 xsessions
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 23 06:01 xtables
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 yelp
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:59 yelp-xsl
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 zenity
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 zoneinfo
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4096 Nov 10 20:00 zoneinfo-leaps
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Oct 25 18:43 zoneinfo-posix -> zoneinfo
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Oct 19 15:58 zsh
```

Comment: On my mac running big sur, I do not have write permissions for `/usr/share` either, just to provide more data, so this definitely has to be because you do not have write permissions. This should explain it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/586954/creating-folders-in-usr-share-folder

Comment: With `drwxr-xr-x 314 root root 12288 Dec 1 07:39 /usr/share`, unless you are `root`, you cannot change this directory.

Comment: But then how do applications isntall their files to usr/share? Most of application files I see on my computer locate their files there upon isntallation if I'm not mistaken. Do they have root privileges? And how?

Comment: @Vahan a program can not easily elevate its permissions. It is common practice to error out and ask the user to run the program with `sudo`.

Comment: Generally the installer for the program will have root privs in order to install the program and its support files.  The program itself will not, as it just needs to read these files (and /usr/share is readable by everyone).  Usually the installer will pop up a dialog asking for an administrator password so it can get root privs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ls -ld /usr/share` to see what the permissions on the directory are (without `-d`, you get the contents and their permissions).

Use code like:

```
if (mkdir("/usr/share/test", S_IRWXU) != 0) {
    perror("mkdir");
    exit(1); }
```

to test the success/failure of the mkdir call and print the reason it failed (and exit) when it fails.  Most likely, you'll see

```
mkdir: Permission denied
```

meaning you don't have write permission to the containing directory.